# Routing from View to a Razor Page action Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an UnderConstruction page which is being handled by MVC. The view has the following code to route a user, after entering their email address to the registration page which is part of the identity scaffolded razor area. The intent is to bring up the register page with their email already populated in the email input.

```
<!-- route to Register Form -->
<form class="form-inline push-10"   method="get">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only text-white" asp-for="Email">Email Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" asp-for="Email" placeholder="Your Email..">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-page-handler="WithEmail">
       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Register
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <a class="btn btn-default" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
     </a>
  </div>
```

and the pages view model

```
 public class UnderConstructionViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Clicking the Register button after entering an email address produces this url

> https://localhost:44367/Identity/Account/Register?Email=testemail@mydomain.com

This brings you to the register page with the email address NOT populated in the email input.

Here is the method in register.cshtml.cs (scaffolded razor area for identity)

```
public IActionResult OnGetWithEmail(string email)
{
   return RedirectToPage("Register", new InputModel{ Email = email });
}
```

The problem is, the method never gets hit. The handler is following convention, and the model is following convention, so I am not sure why the method is not getting hit.

I also tried the asp- tag helpers in the form call, but that produces the same result.

Any help sorting this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any query string values that are appended to the form's `action` attribute, or in this case the `formaction` attribute are wiped out by the routing system when the form is submitted. This appears to be by design: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8621

You can resolve this by adding `"{handler?}"` to the `@page` directive in the Register page. Then the handler name is appended to the URL as a segment rather than as a query string value.